# $.getJSON not able to receive data

Tags: javascript, json

The data passed is a JSON, i can't receive it using this

```
$.getJSON('http://agrimainfotech.com/test/json/json.php?isbn=9789381626344', function(data) {

         alert(JSON.stringify(data));

    });
```

I was able to use the same for another url and it works.

```
 $.getJSON('http://salespump.pumpstationstudios.com/app/services/getemployees.php', function(data) {

             alert(JSON.stringify(data));

        });
```

What is the difference between both the JSON passed and what should i do to make the first url work. I get an array in the server and then i use `json_encode` to make it in JSON format. but still this dosen't work.

Comment: This depends entirely on what the service returns.

Comment: Is the second one a request on the same domain? You won't be able to do cross-domain GET requests without using JSONP. It looks like neither URL is configured to support JSONP.

Comment: Look at your js console for any errors.

Comment: @azizpunjani : `Request URL:
    http://agrimainfotech.com/test/json/json.php?isbn=9789381626344
  
  
    Request Method:
    GET
  
  
    Status Code:
    HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
It doesn't show any error. the second one also gives the same. but it give the output also...
@AndrewWhitaker : Both are different domains, i'm trying to get the data to my html app on localhost. The second one gives result. First one doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

First thing is 1st:

If you are not in the same domain use JSONP instead.

`salespump.pumpstationstudios.com !== agrimainfotech.com`
when it comes to cross domain requests. So it will fail if you try from one to the other.

Comment: I tried this but but it gave no result,
` $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://agrimainfotech.com/test/json/json.php?isbn=9789381626344',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data){

                            alert(data);

                    }
            });`

Comment: @hablema that is because your return data is **not** jsonp.

Comment: ` $.ajax({
                    url: 'http://agrimainfotech.com/test/json/json.php?isbn=9789381626344',
                    success: function(data){

                            alert(data);

                    }
            });`

This dosen't return anything at all...

Comment: @hablema how what should be done? [please read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp)

Comment: Can you help me make this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/VagTe/

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a cross domain issue. You could try to use jsonp if the server supports it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks everyone for mentioning about cross domain requests. It was new for me. I corrected it out by adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` in the sever php script. So now i can make my call from my phonegap app to the server.